# How can I change my Facebook account associated with my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, login, facebook

I want to deactivate my Facebook account and create a new one. How can I associate this new account with my current Stack Overflow account?

Comment: So create your new one first, then add that as an extra login and delete your current one. Go to your user page, click on "My Logins" and then add your new login there.